# hamburgur icon is not showing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

it is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/notification_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/notification_app_bar_main"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/notification_navigationView"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/App_Pink"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"

        />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

it is java class

```
public class FragmentNotice extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
       private ProgressDialog progressdialog;
       private DrawerLayout drawer;
       private RecyclerView notificationrecyclerview;
       private ArrayList<NotificationListModel> arrayList=new ArrayList();
       private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
       private     View view1;
       private CircularImageView navigationheader_image_profile;
       TextView name;
       TextView sign_in;
       TextView view_profile;
       LinearLayout upgrade_layout;
       LinearLayout linearLayout4;
       AppCompatActivity activity;
       ImageView notice_drawer;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notice, null);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            activity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
            activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            drawer = (DrawerLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.notification_drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)view.findViewById(R.id.notification_navigationView);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            notificationrecyclerview=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.notificationrecyclerview);

             toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    getActivity(), drawer,  R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
             drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

            toggle.syncState();

             view1= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
             navigationheader_image_profile=(CircularImageView)view1.findViewById(R.id.navigationheader_image_profile);
             name=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.name);
             sign_in=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
             view_profile=(TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.view_profile);
             upgrade_layout=(LinearLayout)view1.findViewById(R.id.upgrade_layout);
             linearLayout4=(LinearLayout)view1.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout4);
             onNotificationExecute();

             onFetchingUserName();

            return view;
        }

      /*  @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            toggle.syncState();
        }
    */
        @Override
        public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
            toggle.syncState();
        }


        private void onFetchingUserName() {

            String user_id=String.valueOf(HelperEditProfile.read("user id",0));
            String Url = HechatConstants.url+"/api/users/"+user_id;
            GetServiceMethod fetchinguserdetail=new GetServiceMethod(userdetailresult,Url,"GET","");
            fetchinguserdetail.execute();

        }

        Callback userdetailresult=new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void result(String jsonString) {
                if(jsonString!=null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonobject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
                        JSONObject data=jsonobject.getJSONObject("data");
                        String url=     data.getString("fileUrl");
                        name.setText(data.getString("userName"));
                        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(navigationheader_image_profile);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"could not fetch your details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        };



        private void onNotificationExecute() {

             String url= HechatConstants.url+"/api/notifications";
             progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
             progressdialog.setMessage("Fetching notification");
             progressdialog.show();

             GetApiWithHeader notificationlist=new GetApiWithHeader(notificationresult,url,"GET","");
             notificationlist.execute();

        }


          Callback notificationresult=new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void result(String jsonString) {

                if(progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressdialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if(jsonString!=null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
                            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                            if(jsonArray.length()>0){

                                SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                                 simpledateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

                                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {

                                    int actiontype = 0;
                                    boolean issent=false;
                                    boolean isRead=false;
                                    String useridname=null;
                                    String oweneridname=null;
                                    String owenerprofile=null;
                                    String  ago=null;

                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("actionType")) {

                                        if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("actionType").equals("null")){

                                        }
                                        else {
                                            actiontype=  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("actionType");
                                        }

                                    }

                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("isSent")) {
                                        issent=   jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("isSent");
                                    }
                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("isRead")) {
                                        isRead=   jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("isRead");
                                    }

                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user").has("userName")) {

                                        useridname=  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("user").getString("userName");

                                    }


                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("owner")) {

                                        oweneridname =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("owner").getString("userName");

                                        owenerprofile =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("owner").getString("fileUrl");

                                    }

                                    if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("created_at")) {

                                        if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("created_at").has("date")) {

                                            String createdat=     jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("created_at").getString("date");

                                            long time = simpledateformat.parse(createdat).getTime();
                                            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                            CharSequence  agotime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

                                            ago= String.valueOf(agotime);

                                        }

                                    }

                                    arrayList.add(new NotificationListModel(actiontype,issent,isRead,useridname,oweneridname,owenerprofile,ago));

                                }


                            }




                            NotificationListAdapter notificationlistadapter=new NotificationListAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
                            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                            notificationrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                            notificationrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            notificationrecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                            notificationrecyclerview.setAdapter(notificationlistadapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no notification",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        };






        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            //add your switch statement
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if(toggle!=null) {
                toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            }

        }



        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.friends) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Friends_Recyclerview.class);
               startActivity(i);


            } else if (id == R.id.follower) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Followers_Recyclerview.class);
               startActivity(i);


            } else if (id == R.id.following) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Following_Recyclerview.class);
               startActivity(i);

            } else if (id == R.id.match_me) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Match_Me_Recyclerview.class);
               startActivity(i);

            } else if (id == R.id.invisible_mode) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Invisible_Mode.class);
               startActivity(i);

            } else if (id == R.id.blocks) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Manage_Blocks.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else if (id == R.id.rate_us) {

            } else if (id == R.id.faq) {

            } else if (id == R.id.feedback) {

            } else if (id == R.id.logout) {

                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Alert_dialog_box.class);
                i.putExtra("get_data","logout_dialog");
                startActivity(i);

            } else if (id == R.id.privacy) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Privacy_Settings.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            return true;

        }
    }
```

drawer is opening and closing when i swipe ,but hamburgur icon is not showing
[when i swipe from right to left then drawer open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1XXk.png)

[when page open then it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r8Zs.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: remove toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); from fragment

Comment: i did this but it is not working

Comment: post your Activity code.

Comment: have you used navigation drawer in fragment if you then please post the code

Comment: do not set navigation in fragment. from your screen shot, you can do same using activity. add fragment in that activity.

Comment: i got a solution , i have added a icon in right of toolbar then in java class i wrote  notice_drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  @Override public void onClick(View v) {              if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))  {      drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: anyway thanks for trying help me

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line
`toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

You can either user
    `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled (true)` or
For custom Indicator you can use the following
    `toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.your_drawable_file)`;

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

**Instead of:**

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: i tried this then i got null pointer exeception  , java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference  , i am using toolbar not actionbar and i have already added setSuppotActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: can you please post logcat here?

Comment: Process: com.hechat, PID: 25590
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.hechat.Fragment.FragmentNotice.onCreateView(FragmentNotice.java:109)

Comment: sir , i have read  @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        toggle.syncState();
    }  this can be used for showing icon when it is not displaying but i cant be used in fragment

Comment: Why don't you use Activity instead of fragment?

Comment: i cant do this its need of client , drawer is opening and closing but i have to set only hamburgur icon and click on hamburgur icon drawer opens

Comment: move your Toolbar xml from fragment layout to activity layout and from fragment try this: getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: sir , can i add you on skype for asking problem

Comment: i got a solution , i have added a icon in right of toolbar then in java class i wrote  notice_drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  @Override public void onClick(View v) {              if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))  {      drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: Ohh great... Best practice is to use DrawerLayout in your activity class.